# Proper tab correction of objective-c in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, matlab, tabbing

In matlab if you highlight a section of code and press cmd+i on mac it corrects all the indentation.

Is there a similar command for xcode? Say I have a for loop inside a while loop inside a method, yet each line is flush on the left, can I highlight it all and get the tabbing fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that in Xcode as well - default shortcut for that is `ctrl+I`

Answer (score 0):

It is <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> for Xcode.

Also select the code and right-click and Structure

[image]